# PHP getting error when trying to access WP-Admin Dashboard

Tags: php, login, dashboard

I'm unable to get into the backend of my site, and it's throwing the error

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/piximotion/public_html/papillontailor.com//home/piximotion/public_html/papillontailor.com/wp-admin/includes/admin.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/piximotion/public_html/papillontailor.com/wp-admin/admin.php on
>   line 82
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/piximotion/public_html/papillontailor.com//home/piximotion/public_html/papillontailor.com/wp-admin/includes/admin.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/piximotion/public_html/papillontailor.com/wp-admin/admin.php on
>   line 82

Ordinarily when I get an error like this it's because of a plugin, but this time the path is directing me towards the wp-admin folder. I've deactivated most of my plugins in the wp-plugins folder anyway, and I've tried changing what is on line 82 in the admin.php based on what some other answers online have suggested but that hasn't worked. And my PHP is not so great. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: first step is to check if the file exist there, if not better to re-upload wordpress

Comment: Do you see the double path ? Now try disabling other plugins and switch to default theme.

Comment: The theme was really horrible, and I just ended up restoring the most recent backup from my host. Thanks anyways guys

Answer (score 1):

This does seem like a corrupt WP core with missing files. You can attempt to repair it by uploading a fresh copy of core in place. The procedure would be along the lines of [Manual Update documented in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update).

However I want to note that pieces of WordPress core don't just disappear for no reason. You might have been hacking, affected by server issues, or something else entirely. The request to hosting support to look into situation would definitely be wise.